# createSessionsTable equivalent in v3 of AWS PHP SDK?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, session, amazon-dynamodb, aws-php-sdk

I'm trying to use DynamoDB to handle my PHP's session. In version 2 of AWS SDK there was a function called `createSessionsTable` that would create the sessions table `table_name` you specified in registerSessionHandler(['table_name' => `'table_name'`]) as you can [read here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-dynamodb-session-handler.html).

I can't this function in [AWS SDK 3.0](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/)? Has this function been depricated? If so how can I create the sessions table? What is the format for it? Or does AWS initialize it implicitly in v3 and it gets created on the fly now? I can't seem to find anything on Google.

Anyone using DynamoDB session hadler in AWS SDK V3.0 please help.

Answer (score 2):

The createSessionsTable method has indeed been removed in v3 of the AWS SDK for PHP:

- [v2 SessionHandler Method Summary](http://docs.amazonaws.cn/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.DynamoDb.Session.SessionHandler.html)
- [v3 SessionHandler Method Summary](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.DynamoDb.SessionHandler.html)

Per the configuration guidance in the [Session Handler documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/dynamodb-session-handler.html#configuration):

> table_name
> The name of the DynamoDB table in which to store the sessions. This defaults to 'sessions'.
>
> hash_key
> The name of the hash key in the DynamoDB sessions table. This defaults to 'id'.

You can simply [create a table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.PHP.01.html) in DynamoDB with name 'sessions' and primary key with name 'id' of type 'String', and it will match the Session Handler defaults.